# how can we check if condition in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, antd

```
handleClick=()=>{
    console.log("final course values"+ " "+this.state.selectCourseValue)

    console.log("selected teacher"+ " "+this.state.selectedTeacher)
    if(this.state.selectCourseValue ===null  && this.state.selectedTeacher !== undefined)
    {
        console.log("please select")
        message.warning('Add course')
        return;
    }
    else{
        console.log("Sucessfully updated")

    }
}
```

Comment: What is happening with your current code? I can see if condition in the code you have added. !!

Comment: You condition does not makes much sense, maybe you want just `if (!this.state.selectCourseValue) {` If it's an array, you probably want to check whether it's empty.

Comment: i have two values one is teacher value and another one is course value.here i set default courses for teacher. here one teacher has not courses.so i want check condition and have to show message.

Comment: how can get empty drop-down value

Answer (score 1):

If `selectCourseValue` is an array, then your condition should be probably this:

```
if (this.state.selectedTeacher && (this.state.selectCourseValue || []).length === 0) {
}
```

Checking that `selectedTeacher` is not empty and `selectCourseValue` is empty.